# Obtener primer y ultimo registro de varias fechas Mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando crear una consulta que me devuelva el primer y ultimo turno de un conjunto de fechas

Tabla: **fecha_turno**

```
fecha        turno       Cantidad 
2018-01-01     T1           100 
2018-01-01     T2           200 
2018-01-01     T3           300 
2018-01-01     T4           200 
2018-02-05     T2           200
2018-02-05     T3           300  
2018-02-06     T1           200 
2018-02-06     T2           100 
2018-02-06     T3           400 
2018-02-06     T4           500
```

Aquí vemos que el primer y último turno con el que han comenzado es distinto en cada fecha, por ello no puedo hacer un:

```
SELECT cantidad
FROM fecha_turno
WHERE primer_turno = 'T1'

SELECT cantidad
FROM fecha_turno
WHERE ultimo_turno = 'T3'
```

¿Alguien sabría como filtrar el primer o último turno en cada fecha?

Resultado deseado - Primer turno:

```
fecha        turno       Cantidad 
2018-01-01     T1           100 
2018-02-05     T2           200 
2018-02-06     T1           200
```

Resultado deseado - Ultimo turno:

```
fecha        turno       Cantidad 
2018-01-01     T4           200 
2018-02-05     T3           300  
2018-02-06     T4           500
```

Comment: Modifica la pregunta y aporta el SQL (con phpMyAdmin, opción Exportar), e indica el resultado que te gustaría obtener para los datos que aportes. Así, en vez de describirlo, directamente lo vemos y nos resultará más fácil entenderlo y reproducirlo. La consulta está chula, complétala y será un placer ayudarte.

Comment: Ya esta! Gracias por la sugerencia!

Comment: @EynerCordovaPlasencia Si se resolvió tu pregunta, marca como respondida! Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cual es en definitiva el orden? ¿Es la columna `turno`? es decir ¿`T1` es el primer turno y `T2` es el siguiente y así? ¿El formato es siempre `T<num>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viendo en detalle la tabla publicada se aprecia lo siguiente:

```
fecha        turno       Cantidad 
2018-01-01     T1           100  #Primer Turno de la fecha 2018-01-01
2018-01-01     T2           200 
2018-01-01     T3           300 
2018-01-01     T4           200  #Ultimo Turno de la fecha 2018-01-01

#-----------------------------------------

2018-02-05     T2           200  #Primer Turno de la fecha 2018-02-05
2018-02-05     T3           300  #Ultimo Turno de la fecha 2018-02-05

#----------------------------------------- 
2018-02-06     T1           200 #Primer Turno de la fecha 2018-02-06
2018-02-06     T2           100 
2018-02-06     T3           400 
2018-02-06     T4           500 #Ultimo Turno de la fecha 2018-02-06

#-----------------------------------------
```

Si la columna `turno` fuera del tipo `INT` sería relativamente sencillo usar las funciones `MAX` o `MIN` para agrupar los turnos por fecha, pero al ser del tipo `VARCHAR` (lo asumo) se require extraer sus indices para efectuar el `query` requerido.

Para ello se emplea la función [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) y la cadena que se obtenga a partir de ella, se transforma en un entero, por medio de la función [CONVERT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp).

Para este caso concreto se trabaja con lo siguiente:

```
CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(turno,'T',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Entonces ya se podría efectuar una consulta rápida de acuerdo a lo publicado, para después escalarla de acuerdo a lo que se necesite:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fecha,
       MIN(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(turno,'T',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS primerTurno,
       MAX(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(turno,'T',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS ultimoTurno
FROM fecha_turno 
GROUP BY fecha;
```

Se obtiene:

```
    fecha       primerTurno  ultimoTurno
1   2018-01-01       1            4
2   2018-02-05       2            3
3   2018-02-06       1            4
```

Sólo hay que tener en cuenta que `primerTurno` y `ultimoTurno` no son columnas como tal de la tabla `fecha_turno`, por tanto cualquier operación de filtrado que se quiera aplicar sobre ellas, se tiene que efectuar mediante `HAVING` o un `subquery`.

Por ejemplo agregando `HAVING ultimoTurno<4;` al `query` anterior (no olvidar quitarle `;` de `GROUP BY fecha`), se tiene:

```
    fecha       primerTurno  ultimoTurno
1   2018-02-05       2            3
```

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

!Buenas!

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT turno, fecha FROM fecha_turno 
  where fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM fecha_turno )
    OR fecha = (SELECT MIN(fecha) FROM fecha_turno )
  GROUP BY turno, fecha;
```

Te devolverá el turno y la fecha. Donde las comparo para que sea igual a la fecha máxima o la fecha mínima.

En caso que quieras cambiar algo en la estructura, o prefieras obtener otros datos, ten en cuenta el `MAX` y el `MIN`, ya que devuelven o el **máximo** o el **mínimo** y puedes "jugar" con ello.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola @Youshiro, gracias por la aportación. En general, es conveniente que, antes de responder, la pregunta esté correctamente formulada para evitar ambigüedades y malas interpretaciones. Me consta que cuesta esperar cuando se ve tan claro, pero es la forma de conseguir respuestas verificables y de calidad en el sitio. Con respecto a tu SQL, si no vas a hacer totales con los grupos, no necesitas agrupar, con un simple DISTINCT es suficiente y el gasto computacional es mucho más reducido. Un saludo y espero que nos sigamos encontrando por aquí.

Comment: Esta respuesta esta mal. Si la fecha es = al maximo o al minimo, los turnos que no caigan en esos casos no seran tomados en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Si haces lo siguiente

```
Select fecha, min(cantidad) as cantidad
from fecha_turno
group by fecha
```

Vas a obtener el minimo para cada fecha.

Lo mismo se puede hacer para los maximos

```
Select fecha, max(cantidad) as cantidad
from fecha_turno
group by fecha
```

Ahora, si unimos estas dos consultas tenemos para cada fecha el minimo y maximo. Suponiendo que solo hay un turno con ese minimo y maximo, joineamos esa tabla con fecha_turno y podemos obtener cada turno

```
select u.fecha, f.turno, u.cantidad
from (
    Select fecha, min(cantidad) as cantidad
    from fecha_turno
    group by fecha
    union
    Select fecha, max(cantidad) as cantidad
    from fecha_turno
    group by fecha
) as u
inner join fecha_turno as f on u.fecha = f.fecha and u.cantidad = f.cantidad
order by u.fecha
```